# Exercise 1.2 in Hartshorne Chapter I

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I got most of this exercise but there are a few things I am confused about:

> Let $A = \{ (t,t^2,t^3) : t \in k\}$.  Show that $A$ is closed and irreducible of dimension one, find generators of the ideal $\mathcal I(A)$, and show that $k[A]$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring in one variable $k[T]$.

Obviously $A = \mathcal V(Y - X^2, Z - X^3)$, so $A$ is closed.  And the elements of $\mathcal I(A)$ are those $f$ for which $f(t, t^2, t^3) = 0$ for all $t \in k$, i.e. all those $f(X,Y,Z)$ for which $f(T,T^2,T^3)$ is the zero polynomial.  From this description it's clear that $\mathcal I(A)$ is a prime ideal, hence $A$ is irreducible.

The kernel of the surjective ring homomorphism $k[X,Y,Z] \rightarrow k[T]$ given by $f(X,Y,Z) \mapsto f(T, T^2, T^3)$ is exactly $\mathcal I(A)$, so this establishes the last claim.  From here we get that $$Dim(A) = Dim(k[X,Y,Z]/ \mathcal I(A) ) = Dim(k[T]) = 1$$ The only thing I haven't done is find generators for $\mathcal I(A)$, which is the radical of $I = (Y - X^2, Z - X^3)$.  Is $I$ a radical ideal ($\mathcal I(A) = I$)?  I'm having trouble seeing this.  Also, is there a more direct way to compute the dimension of $A$?

Comment: I think a general fact to prove and keep in mind is that if you've got a ring $R$, an element $a \in R$, and a variable $T$ then $R[T]/(T - a) \simeq R$ in such a way that $T$ and $a$ correspond. That, and a few of the more standard rules for quotient rings, is more or less why someone used to these things can see the isomorphism $k[X,Y,Z]/(Y-X^2,Z-X^3) \simeq k[X]$ right away.

Comment: $ - $ w $ + $ rt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may write down the isomorphism of coordinate ring explicitly: $k[X,Y,Z]/(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)\to k[T]$,by $(X,Y,Z)\mapsto(T,T^2,T^3)$ and $k[T]\to k[X,Y,Z]/(Y-X^2,Z-X^3)$, by $T\mapsto X$ are well defined and mutually inverse. Thus the rings are isomorphic. (From this you see the ideal is radical.)